# Where can I get databases of cities/places around the world?

Tags: web-services, geolocation

In dopplr [http://www.dopplr.com] there is an option to fill the city of travel and the site will automatically find the city around the world. Is there any web service or database for such a city lookup?

Comment: Please reconsider your tags. I do not see [tag:data-mining] to be relevant here. It's just a database that you are looking for, nothing related to analysis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.geonames.org/ is useful - HTML query, download and web service.

Also http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/ - you'll need a Yahoo developer ID.

Answer (score 4):

Google maps API includes a [geocoding service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html) and there are [plenty of other options](http://www.google.com/search?q=geocoding%20service)

Answer (score 2):

You could download and process this [list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City#Lists). If you trust it.

Answer (score 1):

The best free database of world cities I have found is from MaxMind. See http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity It also includes geocoding information and population. Uses ISO standard for country and regions.

Comment: This database seems to be defunct now. The download is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [OpenStreetMap Name Finder](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Name_finder).

I don't know if it's necessarily the most complete resource, but AFAIK OSM is free for any use, which may/may not be the case with other options.